# Error in Deleting Azure Storage

Tags: windows, azure, storage

I've been going around the internet searching for a solution, and apparently there doesn't have to be one. I even asked in Microsoft's support forum but they didn't help.

I'm using OSX.

```
Error: Storage account *** has  container(s) which have an active image and/or disk artifacts. Ensure those artifacts are removed from the image repository before deleting this storage account.

at Object.ServiceClient._normalizeError (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/azure/lib/services/core/serviceclient.js:682:23)
at Object.ServiceClient._processResponse (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/azure/lib/services/core/serviceclient.js:335:32)
at Request.ServiceClient._performRequest.self._buildRequestOptions.processResponseCallback [as _callback] (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/azure/lib/services/core/serviceclient.js:183:35)
at Request.init.self.callback (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/azure/node_modules/request/index.js:148:22)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
at Request.onResponse (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/azure/node_modules/request/index.js:891:14)
at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
at IncomingMessage.Request.onResponse.buffer (/usr/local/azure/node_modules/azure/node_modules/request/index.js:842:12)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
at storageAccount_deleteCommand__2 (/usr/local/azure/lib/commands/storage.account._js:135:8)
```

I have an empty image, disk, and container

[Empty Disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwGGl.png)

[Empty Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIMHk.png)

Comment: Can you somehow check if the container has an active lease? That could also stop you from deleting storage account. If I'm not mistaken, you're using node.js SDK. Not sure how you would do it through it. But if you use a tool like Azure Explorer from Cerebrata (it's a Windows-based free tool for blob management), you can view the properties of the container and check the lease status of the container.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have one or more blob with an active lease.  See this blog post on MSDN on how to use node.js (the basis of the Azure cross-platform CLI) to break a lease: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/08/01/node-js-script-for-releasing-a-windows-azure-blob-lease.aspx

Comment: I already saw this, and I tried to make it in my directory. Required the files using the "correct" path (based on filename) but it didn't work. Too many errors on `var cli`